# HttpListener returns bad request 400

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, indy, httplistener

I have the next problem. I have a windows service written in c# using HttpListener. The code of my server class:

```
public class SoaphttpServer
    {
        private HttpListener _listener;
        private readonly IniFile _settings;

        public bool Terminated { get; private set; }

        public void Terminate()
        {
            Terminated = true;
            Common.Cts.Cancel();
        }

        public SoaphttpServer()
        {
            _settings = Common.ReadSettings();
            Terminated = false;
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints = 500;
        }

        public void StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                Common.Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                _listener = new HttpListener();
                _listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8012/");
                _listener.Start();
                while (!Terminated)
                {
                    IAsyncResult result = _listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, _listener);
                    while (!result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000))
                    {
                        if (Terminated) break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Write("StartServer: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static async void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            Log.Write("new connection");
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);

            SoapHttpClient client = new SoapHttpClient(context);
            await client.SomeFuncAsync();
        }

        ~SoaphttpServer()
        {
            if (_listener == null) return;
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener.Close();
        }

    }
```

In command line i executed next command:

```
netsh http add urlacl url="http://*:8012/" user="NETWORK SERVICE"
```

Everything works well from all places. I can accept connection from broweser, or from delphi programm using IdHTTP. But when i'm trying to connect from one programm (i have no code from this program), written in delphi to my service i'm getting in this programm: "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request". Previous version of this programm worked well with my service. I know that there were no changes in communication protocol in this programm. I found out using Wireshark that GET packet comes to my computer, but, as i think HttpListener forming this response (bad request) and sending back it without me. What can be the problem? Maybe i can ovverride some methods of HttpListener and look at incoming request from this prog and find out what is wrong where?

Upd. I have found out that HttpListener is sealed class. How can i find a trouble place?

Comment: It used to work. Nothing changed. Now it's broken. That isn't very encouraging for us. A hornet's nest awaits.

Comment: So... you have one rogue client application, written in Delphi, for which you do not have nor control the source and, furthermore, for which a new version has been released that now fails to correctly communicate with a service you have written - a service that presumably has not changed (and seems to continue to work with other clients just fine) whose source you have posted here.  From my perspective, it sounds like the Delphi client application broke something with its update.  If you don't have the source, you cannot know that it is not broken.  The solution is to speak to that developer.

Comment: I talked with that developer, but he sad that he changed nothing in communication protocol. And i found at the internet that HttpListener may cause "Bad Request" response in some cases, but i can't understand how to get request before HttpListener will send Bad Request response.

Comment: code 400 means - the request is malformatted. You can easy get more specific error from IIS, just redirect your client to "hello word" on iis and can get suffix for error 400 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! I have found the solution.

It's all because by default HttpListener can't parse GET-requests with length more than 255 symbols. 
To solve this problem you need steps:

1. Add to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/services/HTTP/Parameters DWORD (32 bits) key and name it "UrlSegmentMaxLength" and set value = 0.
2. Next you need to restart http service:

   net start http
   net stop http

And that's all! Everything works well!